# Correct way to update $_SESSION username in table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've updated the post since I made a bit of change thanks to @user3282898! Though I still can't push the update to the DB.

The table column `$id`, `$issue`, `$last_mod` has already an existing content, I just need to update the content of `issue and`last_mod`column with respect to its`$id`.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))      
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order");

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
//id value
$id = $_GET['id'];
$last_mod = $_SESSION['username'];

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod=".$last_mod." WHERE id=".$_POST['id']) //update won't work

or die(mysqli_error());

header("Location: form.php");
}
else

{
header("Location: form.php");
}
?>
```

I've tried omitting the `$last_mod` to isolate the issue of updating and find that this statement works:

```js
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved' WHERE id=$id")
```

However it won't work with `$last_mod` in it:

```js
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod=".$last_mod." WHERE id=".$_POST['id'])
```

or

```js
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod=".$last_mod." WHERE job_id=$job_id")
```

Your suggestion/opinion is always welcome, thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Updating $comments column works by the way. Only the $_SESSION username that  doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: you have a db column for each user name?

Comment: Use prepared queries, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is ugly

Comment: ^^ besides `$_POST['id']` and `$_GET['id']` are still open to SQL injection.

Comment: And it should be `UPDATE order.coupon SET last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");` not the above you entered. Because $_SESSION['username'] is not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['username']='$last_mod'
```

You are updating the $_SESSION['username'] field in your table which does not exist!
The $_SESSION['username'] is the username and the column to be updated is the last_mod.

You should do this as i said in my comment:

```
UPDATE order.coupon SET last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
```

Comment: Glad to help :) and instead of writing the update on two different lines, you should do it in a single line.
`UPDATE order.coupon SET comments='$comments', last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");`

Comment: Hi man! I also tried updating it a bit but it won't accept like the first one.
`<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order");
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$last_mod = $_SESSION['username'];

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: form.php");
}
else
{
}
?>`

Probably I missed something with `last_mod='$last_mod'`?
The `issue='Resolved'` works fine though.

I'm kinda new and exploring. Thanks man!

Comment: @David What do you mean it won't accept? The field for last_mod in the database is empty?
Did you get any error? Have you checked if the $_SESSION['username'] have a username or is empty?

Comment: I got an error of "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_query' (T_STRING)" on this line: `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");`. The field of last_mod has an entry on it and the $_SESSION has the username. I can't pin point whats wrong.

Comment: Replace the mysqli_query line with this one: `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod=".$last_mod." WHERE id=".$_POST['id']);` It looks as though you are not closing the SQL statement correctly.

Comment: Hi! I've just tried it and I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)` in `or die(mysqli_error());`. I surely appreciated the help man!

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` before the `or die(mysqli_error());`
It should be like that, `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved', last_mod=".$last_mod." WHERE id=".$_POST['id']) or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: Hi! I tried it as suggested and it's not updating the DB, though there was no error. I'm guessing there's something in setting the `id=".$_POST['id']`. This might be silly but I tested it on, `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'])` and it won't push. However it worked fine on `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE order.coupon SET issue='Resolved' WHERE id=$id")`. But both id setting won't work on `last_mod=".$last_mod."`. Also, I initiated getting the value `$id = $_GET['id'];`
`$last_mod = $_SESSION['username'];` at the start. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @user3282898. I've updated the post for a clearer picture.

Comment: I had some time to do some tests. `mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE test_table SET issue='Resolved', last_mod='$last_mod' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error());` this line works. The issue was the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

that query does not seem to make any sense; so how about ...

```
$sql = "UPDATE `coupon` SET `last_mod` = NOW() WHERE `coupon_id` = ?";
```

because it appears, as if you were trying to insert a `username` as the `last_mod` (last modification) timestamp of a coupon. just add a `die($sql);` whenever being uncertain why generated SQL won't work. besides, using the `user_id` (or the `coupon_id`) instead of the `username` would be suggested; because indexed INT fields are way quicker to query by.

Comment: @user3783243 the single/double quotes are a mess; therefore the string-substitution (while accessing an array index) might not work as expect.

Comment: @user3783243 to me, `last_mod` rather sounds alike a timestamp than a username.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
$last_mod = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = "INSERT INTO coupon(last_mod) 
VALUES ($last_mod)";
```

Comment: `$last_mod` (I'd guess) is a string

Comment: @user3783243 it sounds alike the "last modification timestamp" ...which might be an `INT` epoch timestamp, as mySQL function `NOW()` would return it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is a username, and defined as `last_mod VARCHAR(200)`. I'm going to guess it is storage of the user that created the coupon... although I still would have used userid there..